# Проверка существования таблицы на Postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql

Добрый день, я новичок в разработке! Имя базы Shop, таблица users. Столкнулся со сложностью, в том, что не могу понять, какой нужен скрипт, чтоб проверить существует ли таблица users в базе данных, если нет такой таблицы, то создать ее.Проверку пытаюсь делать вот так:

```
' $table = pg_query($db, "IF NOT EXISTS 
                                    (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME='users')
                                    CREATE TABLE [users] (
                                            id serial,
                                            fio VARCHAR,
                                            mail VARCHAR, 
                                            password VARCHAR 
                                            );
                                     ");'
```

Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582500/how-to-check-if-a-table-exists-in-a-given-schema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> если нет такой таблицы, то создать ее

В этом случае вам вообще не нужно проверять существование таблицы: начиная с уже давно неподдерживаемой версии postgresql 9.1 для `create table` можно указать опцию `if not exists`, именно желаемое вами поведение и обеспечивающую.

```
create table if not exists users (...
```

Создаст таблицу если такой ещё не было или ничего не будет делать.

---

Если же проверка нужна для каких-то других целей, то запрос к `information_schema` вполне нормальный способ:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME='users'
```

С одним правда [важным уточнением](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24089729): здесь так же проверяется, есть ли у вашего пользователя права на доступ к этой табличке. В случае деплоя собственного приложения это обычно не проблема.

Либо, что на самом деле чаще встречается - запрос к системному каталогу:

```
SELECT 1 
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_class c
JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
WHERE  n.nspname = 'schema_name'
AND    c.relname = 'table_name'
AND    c.relkind = 'r'    -- only tables
```

Но это всё равно должен быть именно отдельный запрос, оператор ветвления должен быть на приложении или в хранимой процедуре. SQL сам по себе декларативный язык и оператора ветвления не предусматривает.